# How to map an array of elements for Reach component in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is my component:

```js
import React, { FunctionComponent as FC } from 'react';

type shapeMidNumbersInput = { arrMidNumbers: Array<number> };

const MidNumbers: FC<shapeMidNumbersInput> = ({ arrMidNumbers }): Array<Element> => (
  <section>
    {arrMidNumbers.map(item => (
      <div>{item}</div>
    ))}
  </section>
);

const Caller = () => <MidNumbers arrMidNumbers={[3, 4, 5]} />;

export default Caller;
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Type 'JSX.Element[]' is not assignable to type 'Element[]'. Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from the type 'Element': assignedSlot, attributes, classList, className, and 123 more.
>   Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement'type, props, key

I'm expecting output

```html
<section>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
   <div>5</div>
</section>
```

Any suggestions where I'm going wrong with my typescript code?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to declare the return type of the function `MidNumbers`. `Array<Element>` is the wrong type, and anyway declaring the function variable itself as type `FC<shapeMidNumbersInput>` automatically infers the return type correctly because the generic class does it for you.

```
const MidNumbers: FC<shapeMidNumbersInput> = ({ arrMidNumbers }) => (
  <section>
    {arrMidNumbers.map(item => (
      <div>{item}</div>
    ))}
  </section>
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd realised my mistake because originally I'd returned the array without the 'section' wrapping it. That was in itself wrong anyway because I had no root wrapper. This will serve as a reminder to me. Thanks

Comment: You could return it as a mapped array inside of a React Fragment if you wanted. But that itself is a single node - components cannot return an array, only a single node, which is why React Fragment exists (and is quite useful)